# Are there any examples of using precompiled contracts?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, precompiled-contracts

The thing is I want to create my own custom precompiled contracts, and use it in my private chain of ethereum.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/spartucus/781ab57eee0e8699d15e112b32334213) is my code, but it is not right when I call `hello.say()` in geth attach line.

In geth side, I changed `core/vm/contracts.go` file, add my custom contracts.

```
var PrecompiledContractsHomestead = map[common.Address]PrecompiledContract{
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{1}): &ecrecover{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{2}): &sha256hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{3}): &ripemd160hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{4}): &dataCopy{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{10}): &nativehello{}, 
}

var PrecompiledContractsByzantium = map[common.Address]PrecompiledContract{
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{1}): &ecrecover{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{2}): &sha256hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{3}): &ripemd160hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{4}): &dataCopy{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{5}): &bigModExp{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{6}): &bn256AddByzantium{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{7}): &bn256ScalarMulByzantium{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{8}): &bn256PairingByzantium{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{10}): &nativehello{}, 
}

var PrecompiledContractsIstanbul = map[common.Address]PrecompiledContract{
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{1}): &ecrecover{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{2}): &sha256hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{3}): &ripemd160hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{4}): &dataCopy{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{5}): &bigModExp{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{6}): &bn256AddIstanbul{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{7}): &bn256ScalarMulIstanbul{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{8}): &bn256PairingIstanbul{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{9}): &blake2F{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{10}): &nativehello{}, 
}

type nativehello struct{}

func (c *nativehello) RequiredGas(input []byte) uint64 {
    return 1
}

func (c *nativehello) Run(in []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    out := []byte("Native !!!")
    return out, nil
}
```

And in my test contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract hello {
    string greeting;

    function bytes32ToStr(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string) {

    // string memory str = string(_bytes32);
    // TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "string storage pointer"
    // thus we should fist convert bytes32 to bytes (to dynamically-sized byte array)

        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(32);
        for (uint256 i; i < 32; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }

    constructor () public {
       greeting = "hello";
    }

    function say() public  returns (string memory) {
        bytes32 out;
        bytes32 input;
        // bool success = true;
        // assembly {
        //     success := call(20000, 10, 0, input, 32, out, 32)
        // }
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = msg.sender.staticcall(abi.encode(3000, 10, input, input.length, out, out.length));
        if (success == true) {
            return string(returnData);
        } else {
            return "failed!";
        }

        //return greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some examples [here](https://docs.klaytn.com/smart-contract/precompiled-contracts).

And for the above example, the hello contract should be something like:

```
    function say() public  constant  returns (string memory output) {
        bytes32 out;
        assembly {
            let memPtr := mload(0x20)
            mstore(memPtr, 0x20)
            let success := call(gas, 10, 0x0, memPtr, 0x20, memPtr, 0x20)
            switch success
            case 0 {
                revert(0,0)
            } default {
                out := mload(memPtr)
            }
        }
        output = bytes32ToStr(out);
    }
```